# Load balancing not possible with Zend Framework due to MySQL Adapter Error

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, zend-framework

I recieve the following error message when I set up load balancing between two servers that are running the zendframework called "SocialEngine"

As it looks there is a problem that I can't connect twice to my DB-Server, how can I handle this problem?

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.8.160.132' (13)' in /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngine/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php:352 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngine/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->_connect() #1 /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngine/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(112): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET time_zone =...') #2 /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngine/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(256): Core_Bootstrap->_initDb() #3 /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngine/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(207): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->_executeResource('db') #4 /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngine/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(150): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #5 /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngi in /var/www/html/Test12082013SocialEngine/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php on line 352

**EDIT**
This Error only showns on the second server, the first server can connect properly to the db

Comment: What sort of server is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton we are using two servers (one apache and one mySQL db), the zend framework runs on Linux OS Centos 7

Both are decicated cloud hostings in the same firewall zone

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the appropriate SELinux boolean to allow the web server to communicate with remote databases.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: Okay I will try that, could you explain to me why I need to set this boolean? Because one of the server can actually access the db without problems, how is this caused?

Thank you for your explanation

Comment: We just tested it and one server can connect and the second one shows the error message above. Do you think there could be a configuration problem with the MySQL Server?